# How to make iPhone to communicate to server by using socket?

Tags: iphone, sockets

I know how to make a Java socket in server.
But how to make a socket in iPhone to communicate to server by using socket?

Comment: In fact, I don't know whether implement a Java socket in server is good for iPhone connecting to the server or not.
Can you give me some comment?

Answer (score 1):

Core Foundation has `CFSocket` and `CFStream`. However, there is a library to make using them much nicer.

http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

I recommend checking that out (as well as reading the docs on the Core Foundation stuff to understand it better).

Comment: No, was a bad edit. Was thinking there was a Google library, but found the other and forgot to change the answer. Whoops, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Some resources related to communications on the iPhone:

- [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Stream Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html)
- [CFNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CFNetwork/Reference/CFNetwork_Framework/_index.html) specifically [CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html)()